# Retrieve posts that belong to a list of categories laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need your help to find a solution to create this query. Imagine I have 2 tables: posts and categories, and a pivot table: category_post.

posts: id, title, ...

categories: id, category_name, ...

category_post: post_id, category_id

Now, I am going to retrieve the categories I want:

```
$categories = Category::whereIn('id', $array)->lists('id');
```

After this query I am having a list of category ids and I want to retrieve only the posts that belong to those categories. Not only the posts that belong to one category or another but only the posts that belong to all of those categories.

I hope I explaned myself well.
Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can register a `belongTo` relation for the pivot class. (provided `category_id` and `post_id` are foreign keys.)

```
class CategoryPost extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'category_post';

    public function posts() {
        return $this->belongsTo('posts');
    }

    public function categories() {
        return $this->belongsTo('categories');
    }
}
```

Now, you can call

```
CategoryPost::with('posts')->whereIn('category_id', $categories)->groupBy('post_id')->get();
```

Comment: It works perfectly, I just had to add groupBy('post_id') in order to remove duplicated entries. Thank you!

Comment: I needed one more thing to make it works. Add havingRaw('count(*) > 1') so I can select only the posts that belong to all of those categories at the same time.